How to add extra behaviors to a mapping?
For example, in insert mode, I want to remap <tab> in the following way
if something is true
then
    do my own work
else
    do what <tab> should do if I don't imap it


You can use mapping expresionsions: :h map-expr

As suggested in the comments, you can use an expression mapping to do so.
In this kind of mapping, the right hand side will be interpreted as an expression and its return value will be inserted.
See :help :map-<expr>.
In its most simple form, the mapping could use a ternary and look as follows:
:inoremap <expr> <tab> some_condition?my_own_work:'<tab>'

Where some_condition is your condition, an expression that evaluates to true or false.
And my_own_work is whatever code you want to run.
It needs to return a string.
And finally, '<tab>' is the literal string "<tab>".
See :help ternary and :help expr for more information.
A simple, running example with a global variable as condition:
:let g:condition=1
:inoremap <expr> <tab> g:condition?'this is my tab':'<tab>'

Will insert the nonsensical string "this is my tab" when Tab is pressed and g:condition is true.
